# Converting RealmSwift.List model object into structure

Tags: swift, realm

The topic might not be fully understable but I will explain what I want to achieve.

The exapmle JSON will look like this:

```
  {
     "name": "SomeName",
     "addresses": [
        {
           "city": "Berlin",
           "street": "Dunno"
        },
        {
           "city": "Paris",
           "street": "Dunno2"
        }
     ]
  }
```

The `Realm` objects :

```
public final class PlaceObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    var addresses = RealmSwift.List<Address>()

    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "name" // It's a wrong primary key, it should be some id / auto incremenet id, for example might be like this.
    }
}

public final class AddressObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var city = ""
    @objc dynamic var street = ""

    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "city" // Same as above.
    }
}
```

And then following amazing tutorial to switching from classes to structrues [Using realm](https://medium.com/@gonzalezreal/using-realm-with-value-types-b69947741e8b) (Protocols are included there)

I've achived almost everything what I want except saving into 1 object nested dictionaries / arrays.

The structures looks like :

```
struct Place {
    public let name: String
    public let addresses: [Address]
}

extension Place : Persistable {

    public init(managedObject: ManagedObject) {
        name = managedObject.name
        addresses = managedObject.addresses
    }

    public func managedObject() -> PlaceObject {
        let placeObj = PlaceObject()

        placeObj.name = name
        placeObj.addresses = addresses

        return placeObj
    }

    public enum PropertyValue : PropertyValueType {

        case name(String)
        case addresses([Address])

        public var propertyValuePair: PropertyValuePair {
            switch self {
            case .name(let id):
                return ("name", id)
            case .addresses(let id):
                return ("addresses", id)
            }
        }
    }

    public enum Query: QueryType {
        case name(String)

        public var predicate: NSPredicate? {

            switch self {
            case .name(let value):
                return NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", value)
            }
        }

        public var sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor] {
            return [SortDescriptor(keyPath: "name")]
        }
    }
}

struct Address {
    public let city: String
    public let street: String
}

extension Address : Persistable {

    public init(managedObject: ManagedObject) {
        city = managedObject.city
        address = managedObject.address
    }

    public func managedObject() -> AddressObject {
        let addreses = AddressObject()

        addreses.city = city
        addreses.street = street

        return addreses
    }

    public enum PropertyValue : PropertyValueType {

        case city(String)
        case street(String)

        public var propertyValuePair: PropertyValuePair {
            switch self {
            case .city(let id):
                return ("city", id)
            case .street(let id):
                return ("street", id)
            }
        }
    }

    public enum Query: QueryType {
        case city(String)

        public var predicate: NSPredicate? {

            switch self {
            case .city(let value):
                return NSPredicate(format: "city == %@", value)
            }
        }

        public var sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor] {
            return [SortDescriptor(keyPath: "city")]
        }
    }
}
```

I will get expected errors:

```
error: cannot assign value of type 'List<AddressObject>' to type '[Address]'
        addresses = managedObject.addresses

error: cannot assign value of type '[Address]' to type 'List<AddressObject>'
        placeObj.addresses = addresses
```

My question is how could I convert type `[Address]` to `List<AddressObject>` and in the different way to match a pattern ?

**WORK AROUND**

There is a way to do this in a messy style. Don't save a nasted Array inside `PlaceObject` but create an aditional key for this object and via this key connect these two while retriving them from Data Base. In my opinion it's not a nice way - redundant logic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error is quite self explanatory: you need to convert `List<AddressObject>` to `Array<Address>` and vice-versa, you can't just assign a collection with a different type to a variable. Moreover, why would you pretty much duplicate your model classes by declaring both a Realm model class and a struct for your objects? What is it you cannot achieve using a Realm model class for which you need to create a Struct representing the same thing.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Structs are much faster while are used as a data storage.

Comment: What do you mean by much faster? Did you do actual benchmarking on the issue? Moreover, if your issue is the query speed, retrieve the objects once, make copies of them than use those copies in memory, I am fairly sure that's gonna achieve the same speed as your Struct solution (which by the way seems really inefficient, especially memory-wise).Moreover, your question needs more context, quite a few types are not actually declared in the code of the question (such as the problematic `ManagedObject` for instance).

Comment: @DávidPásztor It would be much better to use the references instead of copies around whole project ? ManagedObject is in the article which I've linked pointing on it.

Comment: If you want to use references, why use a copy of the Realm objects itself, which copies are actually value types and not reference types? Unless you have hundreds of thousands of objects stored in Realm (in which case storing those in memory is a really bad idea), I don't believe you can get any real performance benefits. Moreover, by using structs as copies of your Realm classes you lose most benefits provided by Realm.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Got ya! Thanks for advice :)